# Can I make a cyclic string in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In haskell one can make an infinite list with

```hs
f =
  let ones = "ones":ones
  in ones
```

Is there a way to do this in google sheets?

I tried searching, but I only could find examples of infinite scrolling in google sheets, not infinite strings.

Comment: How would that even work? For example, how would it calculate how big the cell should be? And what would this be useful for?

Comment: "For example, how would it calculate how big the cell should be?" the cell's size is constant, and can never show the full string. "And what would this be useful for?" I want to use it as a kind of gag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't if this is exactly what you need, but you can try with BYROW, like this:

=byrow(B:B,lambda(each,"This is the string"))

(Important, choose a range from another column than the one you want to fill, if not it will be cyclical)

[image]

Comment: This fills multiple cells, I want cyclical in a single cell. Maybe concatenating the entire A (infinite) column into a single cell?

Comment: Yes, just add CONCATENATE( at the beginning of the formula

Comment: You can also use REPEAT("STRING",1000) And change 1000 for another number, obviously infinite I don't think is truly accomplishable

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A))/0; "ones"))
```

[image]

Comment: The review queue flags it as low quality.  Perhaps you should add some explanation  :-)